# IP address of bindings in IIS can they be different to server IP?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

Bit of a noob question, but in IIS, can I create a binding for a site (e.g. abc.domain.com) with an IP address that isn't the server's IP?

E.g. server IP 192.168.3.4
Binding abc.test.com - IP 192.168.3.5

Is this a valid config?

Thanks!

Comment: To what end? It doesn't really make any sense - if the server isn't listening on an IP, how can something on the server listen on that non existent IP?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. If you are needing to bind to another IP, add another NIC or add a secondary IP to the current NIC. Then you could bind to the second IP. If there is more to what you are trying to accomplish, please revise your question to include the end goal.

Comment: Ditto.  Upvote.  In a multi-homing environment it wouldn't make sense.